# Required fields for requests using Autoscaler Resource in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a wrapper for Google Compute Engine and I'd like to do some defensive programming and not allow for the function to be called if the passed Autoscaler Resource doesn't contain all the minimum required fields.

I'm reading the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/autoscalers#resource) but I can't seem to understand which are required and which are optional (besides the ones that explicitly say they are optional or say that if the field is not provided then a default value will be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only required fields are as follows:

```
name
target
autoscalingPolicy.maxNumReplicas
```

and the others have some defaults (as noted in the doc you mentioned).